# Calculating the number of possible paths through grid

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> We are given with four integers $H$ , $W$ , $A$ , $B$ respectively

We have a large rectangular grid with $H$ rows and $W$ columns. Find the number of paths from top left to bottom right moving only right ($R$) or down ($D$) to adjacent cells .

However, we cannot enter the cells in the intersection of the bottom $A$ rows and the leftmost $B$ columns. (That is, there are $A \times B$ forbidden cells.) There is no restriction on entering the other cells.

Example 1 : $H = 2; W = 3; A = 1; B = 1$

Answer : $2$

Example 2 : $H = 10; W = 7; A = 3; B = 4$

Answer : $3570$

Comment: So what do you want to ask?

Comment: Number of ways to reach bottom right

Comment: What have you done so far?  Do you know the number of paths if there is no forbidden rectangle?

Comment: I bet this is from a programming competition of some kind. Codechef maybe?

Comment: No , it is from here https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc042/tasks/arc058_b past contest .

Comment: I ask because the editorial of this solution was in Japanese , and it was very difficult to understand from google translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is no forbidden rectangle i.e. $A = B = 0$. Combinatorics tells us that then there are $\binom{W + H}{H}$ possible paths.

Now we want to subtract all forbidden paths. Note that a path is forbidden if he enters the forbidden rectangle. Let's think of a path as a string over $\{R, D\}$ of length $W+H$ where $R$ denotes a move to the right and $D$ denotes a move down.

We can see that a path enters the forbidden rectangle if and only if more than $H - A$ of the first $B + (H - A)$ moves are $D$'s. So how many strings of length $H + W$ are there where the first $B + (H - A)$ letters contain more than $(H - A)$ times a $D$? We can count this by the following sum: $$S := \Sigma_{i = H - A + 1}^{B + (H - A)}\binom{B+(H - A)}{i} \binom{W - B+A}{H - i}$$

For a given $i$ the first binom corresponds to the amount of strings of length $B + (H - A)$ with $i$ times a $D$. The second binom corresponds to the amount of strings of length $W - B + A$ containing $H-i$ times a $D$.

So the answer would be: $$ \binom{W + H}{H} - S$$

Comment: srry for late reply . I understand the part that i have to make more than (H-A) moves Down to reach a row containing forbidden zone . How is B + ( H - A) Right moves are for columns ? . I am assuming H for rows and W for columns

Comment: Consider the rectangle above the forbidden rectangle. Its height is $H - A$ and its width is $B$ (assuming it is right aligned with the forbidden rectangle). If we make $B$ right moves and $H - A$ down moves in the first $B + (H - A)$ moves then we end up in the right left corner of this rectangle. If we do more right moves and less down moves we're fine. But if we do more down moves and less right moves we'll enter the forbidden rectangle. I just played around with some examples until I got to $B + (H - A)$. And once I had the intuition it was not too hard to argue why that must be correct.